# highcharter highlight one single point in a line chart

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I am using the package highcharter on R and ran into an issue. I would like to highlight some specific points on a line (which is made of many different points). On ggplot, the code would be something like that:

```
library(ggplot2)

diamonds%>%  
head(100)%>%  
ggplot()+ 
geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = cut))+  
geom_point(aes(x = x, y=y, color = cut), data = diamonds%>%head(3))
```

Please note that I, like in the example above, will have several groups. Therefore each point must be associated to right group color.

As it is interactive, I would also like the point to disappear with the line when clicking on the legend to remove the group line.

I found an example which is pretty close to what I want to achieve, but did not manage to replicate it in highcharter, especially when using the hcaes mapping argument. https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s24rk9x7/

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Another update

In the course of trying to figure out why the chart's behavior changed in unexpected ways (tooltips, zoom, etc.), I actually figured out a way to do this without any JS.

Here is a UDF that can be used to create the chart you're looking for. Note that I've made many comments in the code to explain the purpose/process.

```
highlightPoints <- function(dta, x, y, group = NULL, ptRows = NULL) {
  # dta (data frame) x, y, group, and ptRows are within dta
  # x: (string) column name for x-axis
  # y: (string) column name for y-axis
  # group: (string) column name to color the plot by
  # ptRows: (data frame) rows in dta that are to be highlighted points, 
  #                     must contain x, y, and group (if group not null)
  colrs = c("#7cb5ec", "#434348", "#90ed7d", "#f7a35c", "#8085e9", 
            "#f15c80", "#e4d354", "#2b908f", "#f45b5b", "#91e8e1")
  if(is.null(group) == F) {
    iter <- length(unlist(unique(dta[, group])))
    if(iter > length(colrs)) {
      message("There are more groups than this function can accomodate.")
      break
    }
    grList = unlist(unique(dta[, group])) %>% as.character()
  } else {
    iter = 1
    grList = c("")
    group = ""         # to prevent !!sym errors in hcaes()
  }
  
  hc <- highchart()
  lapply(1:iter,             # loop through each group
         function(j) { 
           if(!isTRUE(group == "")) {
             dta2 <- dta %>% 
               filter(!!sym(group) == grList[j])         # if colors assigned, filter
           }
           if(nrow(dta2) > 0) {                          # go through all colors/groups
             hc <<- hc %>%                               # if a line for the group
               hc_add_series(data = dta2,
                             type = "line",
                             id = grList[j],             # set id for legend linking
                             name = grList[j],           # name in legend
                             marker = F,                 # only lines
                             zIndex = 5,                 # points on top of lines
                             color = colrs[j],
                             hcaes(x = !!sym(x), y = !!sym(y), 
                                   group = !!sym(group)))
           }
           if(!is.null(ptRows)) {
             dta3 <- ptRows %>% filter(!!sym(group) == grList[j])
             if(nrow(dta3) > 0) {
               hc <<- hc %>%                             # if a point for the group
                 hc_add_series(data = dta3,
                               zIndex = 10,              # points on top of lines
                               type = "scatter",         # points only
                               id = grList[j],
                               linkedTo = grList[j],     # link to line id for legend
                               color = colrs[j],
                               hcaes(x = !!sym(x), y = !!sym(y),
                                     group = !!sym(group)))
             }
           }
         })
  hc
}
```

To use this function, you'll feed it your data frame, the column you want for the x-axis, y-axis, grouping (optional), and the data for highlighted points (optional)

For example,

- if you were plotting lines based on rows `c(1, 3:6, 13:15)` of the `diamonds` data
- wanted to color by `cut`
- use `x` for the x-axis
- `z` for the y-axis
- highlight the points in rows `c(4, 6, 10)` in the diamonds data

Your code would look like this:

```
highlightPoints(diamonds[c(1, 3:6, 13:15), ],
                "x", "z", "cut", diamonds[c(4, 6, 10), ])
```

Your plot would then look like this.

[image]

If you were using this data—

```
highlightPoints(iris[c(10:15, 80:85, 135:140), ],
                "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Species",
                iris[c(2, 15, 60), ])
```

[image]

You can add to the plot just like any other `highcharter` plot object.

```
highlightPoints(diamonds[c(500:510), ],
                "x", "z", "cut", diamonds[c(200, 507, 500), ]) %>% 
  hc_chart(zoomType = "x")
```

With zoom:

[image]

I've tested it a lot, but I'm sure I've missed something I should have tested for! Let me know if you run into any issues with it.

---

---

##### Updated

I guess my 'meticulous attention to detail' is broken. I'm sorry about missing the mark. Here's an update that I believe really does meet all your objectives.

This uses `htmlwidgets::onRender` to make some changes post-rendering.

In the plot, you'll disable markers for the line graph. In the points series, you'll use `linkedTo` to connect the two traces.

This built-in functionality, `linkedTo`, really only works correctly when you're connecting graphs of the same type (i.e., two graphs that are line graphs). That's where the `onRender` call comes in.

In the `onRender` JS, there are a few things that happen:

- points' colors are reset to match their respective lines' colors
- an id for each series is assigned that matches the series' name—`linkedTo` is connected based on a series `id`
- `linkedTo`, for each *point* series, is updated to match the name of the series

I've added the JS again in a SO JS chunk, so you can see the syntax highlighting. I've added a lot of comments in the JS so that you can understand what it's doing.

Here's the R code.

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = diamonds[1:15, c("x", "y", "cut")],
                type = "line", marker = F,
                hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = cut)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = diamonds[1:3, c("x", "y", "cut")],
                type = "scatter",
                linkedTo = ":previous", 
                hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = cut)) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::onRender(
    "function(el) {
    chart = Highcharts.charts[0].series;
                                   /* get types, names, colors */
    getLines = [];                 /* used to collect line data name/color */
    getPts = [];                   /* used to collect point data names */
    chart.forEach((ser, ind) => {
      nm = ser.name;                              /* get series' name */
      clr = ser.color;                           /* get series' color */
        if(ser.userOptions.type === 'line') {              /* if line */
            getLines.push([nm, clr]);
        } else if(ser.userOptions.type === 'scatter') { /* if scatter */
            getPts.push([ind, nm]);
        }
    });
                    /* connect points and lines traces, update colors, ids, links */
    function indexOf2d(arr2d, findMe) { /* used for find colors between pts/lines */
      return [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], arr2d))).indexOf(findMe);
    }  /* rtns index, each el has index-- '5' in 2d array is the 3rd row, 2nd el*/
    opts = Highcharts.charts[0].options;         /* get options to modify chart */
    for(i = 0; i < getPts.length; i++) {               /* for each point series */
      ind = getPts[i][0]                           /* get index of point series */
      colrInd = indexOf2d(getLines, getPts[i][1]);        /* index matched line */
      lineInd = Math.floor(colrInd/2)                 /* determine row from ind */
      opts.colors[ind] = getLines[lineInd][1];        /* change the point colors*/
      opts.series[lineInd].id = opts.series[lineInd].name; /* change lines' ids */
      opts.series[ind].linkedTo = opts.series[ind].name;   /* updated the links */
    }
    el = document.querySelector('[id^=\"htmlwidget-\"]').firstChild; /* where's chart? */
    Highcharts.chart(el, opts);                     /* send update to plot */ 
  }"
  )
```

All elements:

[image]

With `Good` invisible:

[image]

The same JS used in `onRender` in a JS chunk:

```js
function(el) {
    chart = Highcharts.charts[0].series;
                                               /* get types, names, colors */
    getLines = [];                 /* used to collect line data name/color */
    getPts = [];                       /* used to collect point data names */
    chart.forEach((ser, ind) => {
      nm = ser.name;                                   /* get series' name */
      clr = ser.color;                                /* get series' color */
        if(ser.userOptions.type === 'line') {                   /* if line */
            getLines.push([nm, clr]);
        } else if(ser.userOptions.type === 'scatter') {      /* if scatter */
            getPts.push([ind, nm]);
        }
    });
                    /* connect points and lines traces, update colors, ids, links */
    function indexOf2d(arr2d, findMe) { /* used for find colors between pts/lines */
      return [].concat.apply([], ([].concat.apply([], arr2d))).indexOf(findMe);
    }  /* rtns index, each el has index-- '5' in 2d array is the 3rd row, 2nd el*/
    opts = Highcharts.charts[0].options;         /* get options to modify chart */
    for(i = 0; i < getPts.length; i++) {               /* for each point series */
      ind = getPts[i][0]                           /* get index of point series */
      colrInd = indexOf2d(getLines, getPts[i][1]);        /* index matched line */
      lineInd = Math.floor(colrInd/2)                 /* determine row from ind */
      opts.colors[ind] = getLines[lineInd][1];        /* change the point colors*/
      opts.series[lineInd].id = opts.series[lineInd].name; /* change lines' ids */
      opts.series[ind].linkedTo = opts.series[ind].name;   /* updated the links */
    }
    el = document.querySelector('[id^=\"htmlwidget-\"]').firstChild; /* chart el */
    Highcharts.chart(el, opts);                           /* send update to plot */ 
 }
```

---

---

##### Originally Wrote

For the line graph, disable markers. For the marker plot, specify the data rows that apply.

Here's an example using the `data("diamonds")`

```
highchart() %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = diamonds[1:15, c("x", "y", "cut")],
                type = "line", marker = F,
                hcaes(x = x, y = y, color = cut)) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = diamonds[1:3, c("x", "y", "cut")],
                type = "scatter",
                hcaes(x = x, y = y, color = cut))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Kat,
thanks for your reply.
This result is not acceptable for me. Firstly, all lines have the same color. Also, the color of the points do not match the line color. Finally, the legend does not react as expected. When I click on the legend, I would like the point and the corresponding line to disappear, which is not the case in this example.

Comment: That was an epic fail on my part. Sigh. I've updated my answer. It really should address all of your objectives this time. Please let me know if there is anything missed or if you have any questions.

Comment: This is indeed a great response, thanks for taking the time to write it down. Nonetheless, I get two undesired behaviors from your JS code.
1. The tooltip disappears after one second when not moving the mouse. This does not happen natively with highcharts.
2. The zooming selector triggers alone when resetting zooming. This is rather annoying. If you add "%>%hc_chart(zoomType = "x")" at the end of the example you provided, you will see what I mean.
If you have time to adapt the JS function to correct those points, that would be awesome.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. Let me know what I didn't test for.

Comment: Hello Kat,
Yes, this solution works fine. It is a bit more work to prepare the chart as you must indicate the colors by hand, but the result is great and the zooming options work fine. Thanks for your help.